# BUT IT IS: 'EntryPointAttribute' attribute must be the last declaration in the last file

Tags: f#

I really hate to ask such a stupid question but my frustration is boiling over. I have 3 files in this order:

```
Work.fs
WorkTests.fs
Main.fs
```

This is all of Main.fs

```
module Main 
open Work

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        let p = work "some data"
        printfn "p : %A" p
        0
```

Work and WorkTests (xunit) came first and and upon passing I added Main.fs

I am still getting the last declaration/file error.

I have tried numerous things but to no avail.

For instance if I omit "module Main" I get "Only the last source file ... may omit such a declaration"

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <Tailcalls>true</Tailcalls>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.8.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="FsUnit.xUnit" Version="4.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Work.fs" />
        <Compile Include="WorkTests.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Main.fs" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like there's another file within `<Compile Include="..." />` after your three. Can you show us `.fsproj` file?

Comment: I edited the Q. But I had checked that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem. The only thing that fixes it is changing the name of `Main.fs` to `Program.fs`. Any name other than `Program.fs` has the same problem. But I found that if you remove the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package the build works, but only after building twice in VS. Bizarre. I don't yet know why this is happening.

---

UPDATE:

When you change the name to `Program.fs` there is another build warning: `A 'Program.fs' file can be automatically generated for F# .NET Core test projects. To fix this warning, either delete the file from the project, or set the <GenerateProgramFile> property to 'false'.`.

Adding `<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>` to the FSPROJ fixes this warning and allows you to use any file name.